# Virtual Hosts suddenly stopped working OSX 10.10

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost

I set up Virtual Hosts on Apache using [this tutorial](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) a few months ago and it has been working perfectly.  While developing a WordPress site I had a PHP error and suddenly my virtual hosts stopped working.

Apache works fine, I can access my sites at http://localhost/~username/ but when I visit any of my virtual hosts I get a "refused to connect" "site cannot be reached error".

Doing `httpd -S` shows that all the virtual hosts seem to be working,  but I can't access them in the browser:

```
jimmy-pages-iMac:users maikunari$ httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server church.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/church.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost church.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/church.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost groovysite.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/groovysite.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost home.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/home.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost localnetwork.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/localnetwork.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost mycoolsite.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/mycoolsite.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost mygroovysite.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/mygroovysite.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost myothercoolsite.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/myothercoolsite.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost surovek.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/surovek.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost testing.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/testing.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost various.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/various.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost wordpress.dev (/Users/maikunari/Hosts/wordpress.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/maikunari/Sites"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ldap-cache: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="maikunari" id=501 not_used
Group: name="staff" id=20 not_used
```

I'm loading my virtual hosts from here: `Include /Users/maikunari/Hosts/*.conf`
I've set permissions to 777 on `/Users/maikunari/Sites/`

As I say it had been working fine until the above error occurred, I don't know if a file has become corrupt, a permissions error?

How to troubleshoot this further?  Please let me know if more info is required.

**Update:**
I've found that by changing the port to 8080 in httpd.conf and the Virtual Hosts files makes virtual hosts show in the browser again, but I'm not sure why.  Does this mean something else is using port 80?

Comment: SIGTERM is someone/something ordering the process to shutdown, not that it is failing.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks - I see now that's just me starting and stopping apache. I've removed that section.